# Manage State in Desktop Application?

Tags: java

i wonder session between Web Application and Desktop Application.

In web applications we can use Session or cookies(or HTTP Session - Stateful if use EJB), but in Desktop Application how can i manage state of object? (if not use Stateful ), i usually use managed state in text file or xml file, it mean when user login , user information will save in text or xml file for managed state and when user logout, system will delete text or xml file. I need some suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you mix the concepts. You should not need to hold user information for desktop application, because your application has only one user instead of many users of a web application. Your application already knows who is its user..

But if you need to save user preferences about your application, as expressed at previous post , you can use The Preferences api, or just you can save to a text file.

Comment: Thank you Gursel ! But if i write Desktop Application for one company and they use internal network, What's best way for this case?

Comment: what kind of application?. it is database application?. if it is database application,you can use application server as a middle tier. You can prefer spring or ejb3 as container technology. and also for client server communication , RMI, hessian, rmi over http, even http are your choices. Another choice, you can prefer 2 tier instead of 3 tier.. then your desktop client communicates with database directly,, even in this situation , you can use spring as your transaction manager.

Comment: yes ! it is database application, first i just want create application look like yahoo messenger (i think it use socket) and use Stateful Session bean for managed object state if i use EJB3 and not use Web Technology?

Answer (score 2):

The Preferences API is probably what you're after (I think): `java.util.prefs`

Answer (score 1):

*The java.util.pref.Preferences class, which was added in Java 1.4 is used to store and get persistent (remains on disk between program executions) hierarchical name/values pairs.These preferences are stored in an operating system dependent manner, e.g in the Windows registry or a Mac preferences file.*

So by using Preferences API, same thing is going to happen file I/O etc which you are doing already but will be in a better-manageable way.

Instead, if possible you can try using Map, accessed by respective methods for insertion/retrieval of user state through a singleton class.